# Visual Studio 2019 GitHub - ошибка отправки первого коммита в репозиторий

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

На GitHub'е классически создан `private` репозиторий - с настройками по умолчанию. В VS2019 подключена система `Git` и прописаны реквизиты данного репозитория. В проекте сделано несколько коммитов, и первая их отправка в чистый репозиторий падает с ошибкой в окне вывода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, в локальном репозитории одна ветка "master". VS2019 обновлена, GitHub-расширение также обновлено. Отправка/получение коммитов в других аналогичных проектах проходит нормально.

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: С недавнего времени GitHub, по умолчанию, вместо `master` использует ветку `main`. Надо помнить об этом при создании нового репозитория. При необходимости измените настройки в своем профиле.

Comment: В новом репозитории пока нет ни одной ветки.. По крайней мере, я не нашёл даже как её создать средствами сайта GitHub в данном случае..

Comment: После создания в репозитории первого файла средствами GitHub - ветка "master" проявилась. В настройках GitHub при создании новых репозиториев у меня по умолчанию настроено имя "master" для главной ветви.

Comment: А другие проекты тоже приватные?

Comment: Также приватные и с настройками по умолчанию. Может быть, работает ограничение по объему отправки во free репозиториях?

Comment: [Individual files in a repository are strictly limited to a 100 MB maximum size limit.](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota#file-and-repository-size-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

В отправке присуствовала папка с медиа-материалами на 1 ГБ. Ни один файл проекта не превысил ограничения GitHub - 100 МБ. Однако, при отправке фиксаций в удаленный репозиторий была ошибка без дополнительных комментариев.

После исключения папки медиа-материалов из списка файлов Git ошибка осталась, т.к. остались предыдущие фиксации в истории Git, запомнившие эту папку, которые и являлись причиной ошибки. Видимо, потому что отправка происходит одним пакетом общей длиной, превышающей допустимые 100 МБ.

В итоге, пришлось сформировать проект с чистого листа. Всё заработало!